# Recommended Nodejs TLS options

Tags: node.js, ssl

We run a nodejs https server and we noticed in one of the online SSL checker tools that we use old ciphers (And generally bad TLS options).

We don't really know much about this thing so we were wondering if there is any recommended ciphers list or specific nodejs TLS options we should pass in order to make sure we are most secured.

Thanks

P.S.
This is the online checker we use: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html
We would really like to get an A there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, i ended up using nginx for SSL termination, and used this guide for securing my ssl connections: https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html